# Have you ever seen a Java File close() throw an exception?

Tags: java, exception, file-io

Has anyone ever seen an exception thrown when calling close method on any closable object?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

An `IOException` will be thrown on `close` if the final `flush` fails.  Possible causes include:

- the file system is full, or the user is over quota,
- hard disc errors,
- a file system was forcibly unmounted,
- a remote file system is unavailable due to networking or other problems,
- (possibly) a character encoding error if writing to the file via an `OutputStreamWriter` or similar,
- a device error if the "file" is a device file,
- a lost connection if the closeable is a network stream,
- a broken pipe if the closeable is a pipe to external process,
- and so on.

I have certainly seen some of these.  Others are unlikely.

However, if the data you are writing is important then you should allow for `close` failing.  For example, if your application is writing out a critical file the file system fills up, your application had better notice this before it replaces the old copy of the file with the truncated version.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's not that rare, IMHO if you are working with anything other than non-local disk files.

Close() works if at that point your closable is still valid and open. Many things like pipes, remote files, etc., can die prematurely.

In addition, I have seen code that ignores errors on open and write and still tries to close (e.g., in a finally block).

Answer (score 4):

Not in terms of file-io, but in terms of sockets the close will raise `IOException` when the other side has aborted the connection. For example, when you fire a HTTP request on a (large) webpage and then immediately navigate away by clicking another link on the webpage (while it isn't finished loading), then the server side will get an `IOException` (or a subclass like [`ClientAbortException`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/ClientAbortException.html) in Tomcat servers and clones) when the outputstream of the HTTP response is to be flushed/closed.

Answer (score 4):

Old post and long since answered but here's a real example:

The following code will except out when bufferedWriter.close() is called.  This happens because the BufferedWriter's underlying Writer (the FileWriter) has already been closed and when a BufferedWriter closes, it first attempts to flush any data in its buffer to its underlying Writer.

```
File newFile = new File("newFile.txt");

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(newFile);
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

bufferedWriter.write("Hello World");

fileWriter.close();
bufferedWriter.close();
```

***Note**: If there's no data in the buffer* [comment out the write() line or add a flush() call] *then no exception will be generated*

Answer (score 3):

I haven't, but it's possible. Imagine if there's an `OutputStream` that for some reason hasn't written to the file yet. Well, calling `close()` will flush out the data, but if the file is locked - then an `IOException` would be raised.

Answer (score 2):

Try yanking a USB drive with an open file on it.  If it doesn't give an exception I'd be pretty surprised.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try to force this by unplugging the disk your file is on. But on any `Closable`? I think it would be easy to get something that uses a socket to throw an exception upon closing.

Answer (score 0):

I have - in my unit tests against mocks ;)