# When will an java.io.InputStream for a local file ever throw an exception when closed?

Tags: java, file-io, exception

Good afternoon all. I am aware that if we [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#close%28%29) an [java.io.OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html), [it may throw an IOException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2765774/632951) when there are hard disk errors.

As for [java.io.InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), [Javamex](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/input_stream_error_handling.shtml) states that:

> > A normal closure of a network socket actually involves a closure request (TCP/IP FIN packet) being sent over the connection and waiting for the other end to acknowledge this closure request. (In fact, the other end of the connection then in turn sends a closure request, which the closing end acknowledges.) So in the case of a socket input stream, a closure operation actually involves sending traffic over the connection and the closure can thus fail with an error.

Now I was wondering exactly under what circumstances will a [java.io.InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) (or sub class) for a local file (network access **not needed**) *ever* throw an exception when we call [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#close%28%29) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one situation:

- Another part of the application has mistakenly closed the underlying file descriptor associated with the InputStream. When the Java runtime calls the system `close()` function, it may get an `EBADF` error indicating that the file handle is invalid.

The above situation probably indicates a serious bug somewhere else in the application.

Comment: Besides that, are there any other possibilities that an InputStream will throw an exception when closed?

Comment: I don't know, it depends on your kernel. Perhaps your kernel is configured to update the atime (access time) for files when you close them, and for some reason it cannot do so. Errors on closing files used for input are rare. Are you looking for something specific?